# school exersise/ Differentiation

Tags: calculus, education

If $f$ is differentiable in ${\bf R}$ and for every $x \in {\bf R}$, 
$$
     f(x+\cos x)-f(1-x)
\leq x\cos x ,
$$
then prove that $f'(1)=1/2$.

How is a school kid supposed to solve this exercise ? 
Thank you very much !

Comment: That must be one heck of a school...

Comment: Or did you assume that we would know the answer, and you're just wondering if we think it's appropriate for school kids? :)

Comment: I am a math major and more or less I constructed this limit after thinking for a while... I was impressed because that exercise was in an exam of mine when in high school... I still cannot either find a more suitable way for solving it neither do I know for sure if it suitable for high scool students. So is there another way ? A way less demanting I wonder..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim_{x\to 0}\frac{f(x+\cos x)-f(1-x)}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}{\bigg[(1-\sin x)f'(x+\cos x)+f'(1-x)\bigg]}=2f'(1)$$ We also have, for all $x>0\in\mathbb{R}$ that $$\frac{f(x+\cos x)-f(1-x)}{x}\le \cos x$$ and for all $x<0\in\mathbb{R}$ that $$\frac{f(x+\cos x)-f(1-x)}{x}\ge \cos x$$ These imply that $$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{f(x+\cos x)-f(1-x)}{x}\le 1$$ and $$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{f(x+\cos x)-f(1-x)}{x}\ge 1$$ respectively. But the limit exists, so these one-sided limits must agree and therefore $$2f'(1)=1$$ from which the claim follows.

Answer (score 1):

By using the definition of the derivative and L'Hopital's rule to get

$$\begin{align}
f'(1)=\lim_{x\to0}{f(1)-f(1-x)\over x}&\le\ge\lim_{x\to0}{f(1)+x\cos x-f(x+\cos x)\over x}\\
&=1+\lim_{x\to0}{f(1)-f(x+\cos x)\over x}\\
&=1-\lim_{x\to0}(1-\sin x)f'(x+\cos x)\\
&=1-f'(1)
\end{align}$$

where, in the first line, the $\le$ sign applies when $x\gt0$ and the $\ge$ sign applies when $x\lt0$ (i.e., by taking the limit from the right for one inequality and from the left for the other).